# Missing reference in Visual Studio after download project from TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

Hello i have project with all packages in TFS server. After downloading the project from TFS, i dont have references in solution. In References are all packages but with yellow rectangle and in packeges folder are all packages. How i update references? What is the proper procedure for working with TFS? Which files from ASP MVC project send to TFS?

Comment: You probably need to restore the nuget packages. Rightclick the Solution and choose "Restore missing nuget packages" from the context menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way, just follow below stpes:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Manually delete the local “packages” folder
3. Reopen the solution, and rebuild. (**Nuget should restore the
   packages**)

Source Link: [Missing Nuget Packages on TFS Build Server](http://robertgreiner.com/2013/09/team-foundation-service-build-error-nuget/)

Or run the update-package -reinstall command to reinstall all referenced packages.